# Why does the magnification increases on decreasing the focal length of objective in a compound microscope?

Tags: optics

In a compound microscope there are different objectives with focal lengths largest to shortest. On applying lens formula what I get, as the focal length decreases the distance and height of the image formed by objective decreases. But it is said smaller the focal length of objective more magnified is the image formed by it. Why don't my ray diagram don't conclude to this point. Iam stuck over this point. Please, clear this point for me that how does the image magnified as the focal lenth decreases(for objective lens)

Comment: Images can be added primarily by using the the editor toolbar button insert image toolbar button (*this image is a square with a picture of a mountain and a dot inside it. It appears just after the {} button*). This brings up a special interface that allows you to upload an image online (through the imgur hosting service) through us - even from your clipboard. Alternatively, it can be input similarly to adding a link:

Comment: Please give the correct answer

Comment: I dont know the answer. I was just suggesting to upload the pic. That would increase chances of someone answering imo. But i can maybe figure out the answer i used to know this. I’ll look and reply if i know

Comment: By compound telescopes, some people mean a combination of mirrors and lenses. I assume you mean only lenses. (1. Is that right?) One definition of objective is the front-most lens facing the object,  (2.but you mean what? Every lens in the telescope? Every lens except the eyepiece?) (3. Are the lenses all convex (convergent) or concave (divergent) or a combination?). Convex and concave lenses have different effects from increasing focal length.

Comment: I cant figure it out. it does seem to me that the first lens (closest to the y does no magnifying. only the second lens in, and the fourth, and the sixth, etc do any magnifying. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refracting_telescope
See the first pic under “Refracting telescope designs”
I dunno if that helps at all.